# Will Allah forgive me?

Tags: sin, homosexuality

I’m a girl and I flirted and did things with another girl. I just read about the punishments for that and it’s really severe, will God ever forgive me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES.**
Allah’s forgiveness is limitless. Don’t stop repenting regardless of what the sin is, regardless of how big it is. Repenting and prayer will take you away from hell and sinning. Repent, it’s your only source of salvation.
Allah loves to forgive.
But your end of the bargain is to:

- change your way
- get closer to Allah
- be sincere in your repentance
- try and never do it again

Even if you do fall into that sin again, repent.
Do it again? Repent.
Again? Repent.

While repenting is good, you must also do your part to not fall into sinning because sinning can take you away from Islam.

Sometimes, Shaytaan may lure you to repent later, but that chance may never come. So you’ll soon end up falling deeper and deeper into sin. What if it’s too late? What if you die before you repent? What if you fall astray?
Sinning takes you away from your Deen. The only way back is to repent.

And understand zina is a major crime in Islam.
I can’t advise you to get married considering you are lesbian, but if you’re at risk of committing zina (or again) get married to someone of the opposite sex.
If that’s not possible, seek refuge from Allah and fear Him. Repent and cut off contact with that girl if you know you’ll end up falling into that sin again.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is the (Rehman) Most Merciful of all.  He likes the people who turn to Him in repentance.

Following are some quotes related to your question:

"***Surely God loves those who turn much (to Him), and He loves those who purify themselves.***" — Quran, Sura 02 (Al-Baqara), ayah 222

"***God accept the repentance of those who do evil in ignorance and repent soon afterwards; to them will God turn in mercy: For God is full of knowledge and wisdom. Of no effect is the repentance of those who continue to do evil, until death faces one of them, and he says, "Now have I repented indeed;" nor of those who die rejecting Faith: for them have We prepared a punishment most grievous***." — Quran, Sura 04 (An-Nisa), ayah 17–18

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said, "***Every son of Adam sins, the best of the sinners are those who repent.***" — Sunan al-Tirmidhi, Hadith no. 2499

In Sahih al-Bukhari, Anas ibn Malik narrates: Allah's Apostle said, "***Allah is more pleased with the repentance of His slave than anyone of you is pleased with finding his camel which he had lost in the desert.***" — Sahih al-Bukhari, 8:75:321.

There are plenty of Hadiths and Ayats emphasizing everyone to ask for forgiveness which clearly means that Allah (SWT) wants sinners to turn Him and ask for forgives and He is the only one who is the Most Gracious and the Most Merciful of all.